# Should UNIX users have the same group

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a web server (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS if needed) multiple people use with Apache, PHP5, and MySQL installed. All users have access to SSH. All users home directory's are `/home/USER` I was wondering:

1. What usergroup should users be in; or should they have their own usergroups()?
2. What user and group should Apache run under?
3. What file permissions should the users `/home/USER/public_html` and `/home/USER` directory's be, as well as subsequent files (including such PHP files w/ sensitive information such as DB passwords)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu/Debian & variants the Apache2 daemon runs as `www-data`.

This is a difficult question to answer specifically, because it depends upon your particular environment & business needs, but very broadly:

- An "old-school" *nix way of doing things might be to create a group of `webdev` users on your box, and to `chgrp` the directories and files they work on to `webdev`. We do that on our dev boxen & it works fine.  These working dirs we put in `/var/www` or `/var/www-ssl`. Please note that traditionally, `public_html` directories are personal sites.  Some orgs create project level users, I dislike this because I believe user accounts should be assigned to people, as was intended.
- A more contemporary way to deal with might be to vritualize and just give each user their own VM to work in, and then let them commit code as necessary, this scales better.

A note is that if you are buying SSL certificates for web applications, it makes sense to build VMs for each web app, as name virutual hosting in Apache2 is not possible with SSL.

Web applications should have their own database users & passwords, with only the requisite DB permissions, which are often placed in conf files whose permissions are only as permissive as necessary, i.e. readable only by the webserver, not in a directory with indexing on, etc.

Yours was a general question, I hope this broad answer was helpful.

Comment: I started up an EC2 instance to try this out, i'm getting "chgrp: changing group of `public_html': Operation not permitted"

Comment: I guess more so when you say "i.e. readable only by the webserver, not in a directory with indexing on, etc." how do I allow it so people can't just `nano /home/test/public_html/conf.php` and read it's source

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no definitive answer for this to question: some people prefer to have each person have their own group, some people were to have a default "users" group. Probably best to leave whatever is the default on Ubuntu.
2. If you're using the Apache package included with Ubuntu (not a bad idea), leave the defaults unless you have a good reason not to. If you have to ask what the good reasons are, then you don't have them. :) Even if you roll your own package, it may be a good idea to use the Ubuntu defaults.
3. If you're going to use the "userdir" module so that folks can do something like http://example.com/~user1, then the execute bit ("chmod a+x ...") needs to enable on both /home/USER, and read and execute ("chmod a+rx ...") on /home/USER/public_html.

As an addendum to (1): if there are various projects going on, then users will probably have supplemental groups in addition to their primary one.

Comment: Userdir does not require a+rx. You only need r on directories when allowing listings.

Comment: I started an EC2 instance to try this out in; created 2 users (test and sneakyguy). I set /home/test/public_html to drwxr-xr-x and set a PHP document to -rw-r-----. Apache is set by default to www-data:www-data. I get no 403/404 but I don't get any output (under -rw-r--r-- I get output). The file is set to test:test. Any idea of what I should change to be able for apache to access said file but not allow other users to access it by `nano /home/test/conf.php`

Comment: Seemed to find a fix; just made www-data user a member of test. Problem seems to be solved. Thanks again and DFTBA (Don't Forget to be Awesome) :)